# Can I calculate the downhill force with the data of a smartphone sensor?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, sensor

*Apologizes for the long explanation, I couldn't find a shorter one.*

I'm working on a project and want to calculate the downhill force only with data I can get with the sensors of a smartphone.

I have access to the following data:

- rotation
- "acceleration"
- mass of the phone

### Explanation how a smartphone sensor works

"Acceleration" because a smartphone sensor apparently cannot really measure acceleration. 
As far as I understand it, there is (as a model) some small box in it and sensors that measure the current position of the box.

If it's in the middle, there is no acceleration (according to Newton's first law):

[image: no force]

(The image above ist simplified to two dimensions.)

If there is a force / acceleration, the position of the box in the middle is a different one and the sensor calculates the acceleration in g.

[image: force / acceleration to the bottom left]

I have access to that data.

The problem is that I get a "acceleration" pointing downwards all the time because gravity pushes the box down.

[image: normal state of the box in the smartphone with gravity]

Using the rotation data of the smartphone and a bit of trigonometry I can calculate the actual acceleration of the smartphone without gravity.

### The problem

This is where the dilemma comes in. **I want to be able to get the downhill force but I still want to remove the normal force and gravitational force from my data.** I'm thinking about a solution for over a month now, but I couldn't figure out one yet.

[image: 3 forces]

I can not figure out a way how to do this. I know how to get two forces of which one is the downhill force and the other is the normal force using trigonometry, but I then don't know which is which.

**Is it possible to find out which of the forces is the normal force and which is the downhill force?**

It could be that I'm mixing the terms "force" and "acceleration" here a bit because it doesn't really matter in that context. Given the mass of the smartphone / the box I can calculate both from wach other.

### [Why I think that this question belongs to Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site/4536#4536)

This question is asking about the possibility of calculating an acceleration in a reference system using data in a different system. It's not about building a device to measure acceleration, neither is it about how to do the maths in trigonometry.

I ask for the general possibility of distunguishing the normal force from the downhill force using only rotation data.

Comment: Isn't the downhill force gravity?

Comment: @KyleKanos I honestly don't know how it is officially managed, but what I learned at school is that there is a "normal force" and gravity and the movement of the object results out of them, so yes, the downhill force is there because of gravity but it has a different direction and strength because it goes, well, downhill. See the 4th image in the question.

Comment: Right, so then it's just $mg\cos\theta$. Though, I would have assumed that any accelerometer built into an earth-based device would be normalized to $g$ so any acceleration recorded is in addition to $g$. Is this not the case for smartphones?

Comment: I have access to data that tells me that there is a acceleration of $g$ downwards and I have access to data that tells me that there is no acceleration at all, even when I let my device drive down a hill. This is because the data 2 is without any gravity, so no downhill force as well. What I want is the downhill force only without the normal force. Data 1 is with both downhill and normal force and data 2 is without downhill force and without normal force.

Comment: I have Physics Toolbox Suite, Sensor Kinetics, and Accelerator Analyzer. All can be set to measure either zero or $g$ vertical acceleration when level. All of them show 3 components of acceleration. If I tilt the phone, the components change according to the angle.  If the phone is parallel to the hill, you'll have the component of acceleration parallel to the hill. $F_{downhill}=ma_{downhill}$.

Comment: @BillN Yes, I will have an acceleration parallel to the hill, but I will also have another in reality not existing acceleration when I just hold the smartphone still. I'm looking for a solution that only shows me an acceleration when my device is actually moving.

Comment: In other words, I don't want the data to change depending on the angle, but I still want to be able to measure the downhill force.

Comment: To measure that force you must know the direction. That means you have to know the orientation of the phone relative to the net acceleration.  Smartphones are not magic; they depend on physics.

Comment: @BillN That's a good point. Is there any mathematical argument that I can not distinguish the normal and the downhill force without knowing the direction of one of them? This would be enough for an answer I think.

Comment: In the best case scenario what you can measure is acceleration 
(either including or excluding g, depending on the calibration). Thus the device in measuring the total force (again, including or not gravity). In such case, there is no way to tell what forces are acting, as any force can always be a sum of many other forces. The device will never be able to isolate the force you want to isolate. So, as the other comments said, you have to have a model that describes your specific situation to compute the force you want based on the measurements you have.